# Issue with service method call in .NET Background Service , Issue with Scope

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I'm facing a weird issue not sure, it's related to `scope` or `async-await`.

Basically, I've a Background service (singleton), which is registered as:

```
services.AddHostedService<JobBackgroundService>();
```

the implementation, is simple as below:

```
public JobBackgroundService(
      ILogger<JobBackgroundService> logger,
      IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
          _logger = logger;
          _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
}

...
using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
var _detailServiceAsync = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDetailServiceAsync>(); 
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase) },
};
var deserializedMessage = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<NotificationObject>(<custom-notification-as-string>, options);
await _detailServiceAsync.OnCreated(deserializedMessage);
```

the above code works as expected.(data stored in detail table)!!

Now I've a requirement to introduce a new IMessageService (via NuGet) and after invoking the `_detailServiceAsync.OnCreated`, need to Invoke `SendAsync` method of messageService based on result.

I changed my code as below :

```
public JobBackgroundService(
      ILogger<JobBackgroundService> logger,
      IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
}

...
using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
var _detailServiceAsync = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDetailServiceAsync>();
var _messageService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMessageService>(); //<<< Changed code
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase) },
};
var deserializedMessage = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<NotificationObject>(<custom-notification-as-string>, options);
var result = await _detailServiceAsync.OnCreated(deserializedMessage);
if(result)
    await _messageService.SendAsync(deserializedMessage); //<<< Changed code
```

**This doesn't work**, `SendAsync` does execute, but I don't see data in DB and there is no error/exception as well.

However for testing : if I move the `_messageService.SendAsync` call above `_detailServiceAsync.OnCreated`, **Then both functions works**. Data does get stored in DB(message & detail tables).

```
await _messageService.SendAsync(deserializedMessage); //<<< moved up
var result = await _detailServiceAsync.OnCreated(deserializedMessage);
```

I tried calling the `SendAsync` as callback function, but still same issue.,

I tried passing `IMessageService` to DetailService and called `SendAsync` inside `OnCreated` method, but then also same issue. Looks like `SendAsync` just doesn't work as soon as `_detailServiceAsync.OnCreated` invoked/executes.

Not sure what I'm missing here ?

**Updated part below :**

After debugging more, the reason found is the order of dbcontext SaveChanges. Currently there are 2 dbContext in picture : one is `MyAppDbContext` & another one is `ExternalAppDbContext` added by NuGet package (in it own implementation) exposed as Middleware.

My application dbContext is added as  `services.AddDbContextPool<MyAppDbContext>(...)` and NuGet DbContext is added as `serviceCollection.AddDbContext<ExternalAppDbContext>(....)`

So when `MyAppDbContext.SaveChanges();` gets called first, then ExternalAppDbContext saveChanges **doesn't work**., but if order is reversed : means `MyAppDbContext.SaveChanges();` called after external one, then everything works as expected.

though my problem is solved, but still curious to know : what is leading to this behavior, is it something with EFCore or the way context is being added to MyApp. Online research didn't help much, so posting here to get some insights and to know the root-cause of it.

Comment: wrap your code into a ````try-catch```` block and log any exceptions. maybe it helps to find the problem.

Comment: @cly Yes, did that too, now it's already in `try-catch`, but no exception occurs, code executes but nothing happens.

Comment: Goto Debug / Windows / Exception settings and make sure 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions' is checked, and try again.

Comment: @Steven CLR exception switched on but didn't get any exception, since `SendAsync` is method in another Nuget lib, so can't debug that, however just by moving it before `OnCreated` everything works. Its really something weird that is happening in background.

Comment: @anoop does is result true? ie. if(result) because your example removes this condition - sorry if is silly question

Comment: @mattsharp Yes result variable does resolve to true :), even without this condition, it simply doesn't work. It's something related to `OnCreated` invocation (not execution, as there are no errors) , that I'm not able to figure out.

Comment: We can't tell why `_messageService.SendAsync` and `_detailServiceAsync.OnCreated` misbehave without the actual code. There's no database code in the question so we can't even guess what is supposed to write to the database. `async/await` has no issues. Singletons don't swallow errors. There's no error handling or logging code in the question so there's no way to know if something went wrong or not.

Comment: If the order matters, it's quite possible that one of those methods fails while the other keeps a transaction open. Many of the fake repository implementations that float around use explicit database transactions or TransactionScope instances that have to be completed explicitly even after a modification operation completes. Or one of them starts a background task with `Task.Run` but doesn't await it. We can't guess